# setOnItemClickListener in only specify list elements

Tags: android, list, textview, onitemclicklistener

I have a list composed by different TextViews managed by a custom adapter.

list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FDD017" >

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#fd1726" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/out1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#17c4fd" />

    <View android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#236e01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/out2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#17c4fd" />

    <View android:id="@+id/line3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#236e01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/out3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#c6c6c7" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I use setOnItemClickListener to perform an action when clicking on ListElements .

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter_view, View view, int position, long id ) { MyAction(); }
    });
```

Is it possible to start setOnItemClickListener only when clicking in *R.id.out3* TextViews and do nothing in clicking on *R.id.out1* and *R.id.out2* ?

Comment: Dont do this `lv.setOnItemClickListener` instead handle item clicks in the adapter, where you can manage which tv was clicked

Comment: you really have to go through some basic listview examples. Setting click listener for some views inside a listView item is a basic topic.See here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html. Also, I recommend to use a recyclerView instead, it´s a better listView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: Yes, you can do as per Tim said or you can do like check the id of View in onItemClick like,

If(view.getId()==R.id.out3){
//Do your stuff here
}

Comment: use individual textView onClickListener() instead of using listView onItemClickListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you getView like below only set `setOnClickListener()` to `R.id.out3` `TextView`

Also remove below code.

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter_view, View view, int position, long id ) { MyAction(); }
    });
```

GetView method.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate dahsboadrf_single_row.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.out1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.out1);
            holder.out2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.out2);
            holder.out3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.out3);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        holder.out1.setText(""); // your logic
        holder.out2.setText(""); // your logic
        holder.out3.setText(""); // your logic

        holder.out3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // And you are done.
            }
        });
        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        TextView out1, out2, out3;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to do this, you can set the global `OnItemClickListener`, and then the view is available. (You can even return the view from your adapter using `getView(position)` if you wanted but there's no need for that)

You can then make a check on that view, verify it's the one you want, and complete an action, else do nothing.

The other way, which is a bit cleaner in my opinion is to simply put `OnClickListeners` on the views in your custom adapter.

Hopefully you're using a `ViewHolder` pattern. Inside you're `ViewHolder` when you define the views, you can also go `out3.setOnClickListener(this);`

Then handle the `onClick` like you would any other way, only that view will have click events registered.